# How do I define a structure instance in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy data type defined like this for example:

```
import numpy as np

Mytype = np.dtype([
    ('x': np.float32), 
    ('y': np.float32), 
    ('flag': np.uint8)
], align=True)
```

So what is the simplest way to create an instance (numpy tuple) according to this type?

I tried this:

```
instance = Mytype(x=2.4, y=5.3, flag=12)
```

That led to the error: `TypeError: 'numpy.dtype[void]' object is not callable`

I looked at the examples here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html but I have not found a solution for **exactly one instance**. All suggested cases are for arrays only. So I could do this:

```
instance = np.array([(2.4, 5.3, 12)], dtype=Mytype)[0]
```

It works correct but it looks too complicated. I guess there is an easier way without creation of an extra array.

Comment: This is for defining the dtype of a *structured array*. You don't "create instances" of it, **it is not a `type`**, it is a `numpy.dtype`

Comment: Hang on. I've asked this before.

Comment: Note, the `type` of your instance is `numpy.void`, if you look at the help page, it explicitly states "Structured `void` scalars can only be constructed via extraction from :ref:`structured_arrays`". What is it that you are actually trying to do? This sounds like the XY-problem

Comment: You can avoid the array only if you're willing to pack the data into memory yourself.

Comment: @MadPhysicist the accepted answer is basically what the OP has...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga between your comment and the authority of the answerer, which I have considerable respect for, it's pretty unlikely that there's an alternative. I've come up with one, but it's pretty obscene in the second answer

Comment: @MadPhysicist ah, didn't notice it. Whether it's possible or not I think the important point is *that it isn't meant to be used that way*. Which is why I am asking the OP what they are actually trying to accomplish

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Seems like the same thing I was trying to accomplish when I posted my question, but I'll let OP speak for themselves.

Comment: you can refer to https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html

`Mytype = np.dtype([('x', np.float32),  ('y', np.float32),  ('flag', np.uint8)], align=True); 
np.array([(1.0,0.1,100) , (2.0, 0.2,200)], dtype=Mytype)`

Comment: `np.float32` is a function, not the actual `dtype`.  `Mydtype` and `np.float32(3).dtype` are instances of `np.dtype`.  `np.float32` is not, even though it is often used as a 'shorthand' for the dtype.